# App crashes when calling getResponseCode()

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

Here's my code

```
public static ArrayList<KeyValue> peticionRest(final ArrayList<KeyValue> parametros, final String funcionAPI, final String metodo){

    ArrayList<KeyValue> respuesta = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        respuesta.clear();

        String urlParametros = URLEncoder.encode(parametros.get(0).getKey(), "utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(parametros.get(0).getValue(), "utf-8");
        for (int x = 1; x < parametros.size(); x++){
            urlParametros += "&"+URLEncoder.encode(parametros.get(x).getKey(), "utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(parametros.get(x).getValue(), "utf-8");
        }

        String stringURL = "url to site";
        URL url = new URL(stringURL);


        HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        myConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        if (metodo.equals("post")){
            myConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < parametros.size(); x++){
            myConnection.setRequestProperty(parametros.get(x).getKey(), parametros.get(x).getValue());
        }

        if (myConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {


            InputStream responseBody = myConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader responseBodyReader = new InputStreamReader(responseBody, "UTF-8");
            JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(responseBodyReader);
            jsonReader.setLenient(true);
            jsonReader.beginObject(); // Start processi ng the JSON object
            while (jsonReader.hasNext()) { // Loop through all keys
                String key = jsonReader.nextName(); // Fetch the next key
                String value = jsonReader.nextString();
                respuesta.add(new KeyValue(key, value));
            }
            jsonReader.close();

        } else {

            respuesta.add(new KeyValue("ok", "false"));
            respuesta.add(new KeyValue("error", "error en la peticion"));
        }
        myConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return respuesta;

}
```

I get a "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0" because respuesta is empty.
If i log the url and click it, it works fine.
The program stops when it reaches myConnection.getResponseCode()

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You problem is

> "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

There are two `List` in your code .So it may cause in it .

In your code .

```
 String urlParametros = URLEncoder.encode(parametros.get(0).getKey(), "utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(parametros.get(0).getValue(), "utf-8");
```

You use `parametros.get(0).getKey()` .It may be the problem .

Try this.

Before call `parametros` in your code .

```
if(parametros != null && parametros.size() > 0){
    // you can do something here 
    String urlParametros = URLEncoder.encode(parametros.get(0).getKey(), "utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(parametros.get(0).getValue(), "utf-8");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't fit my problem. I already checked that parametros isn't null, the problem is with resultado, because my app crashes when calling to getResponseCode() and i don't know why.

Comment: Good luck to you .@MZab